# Why does this reversed StringBuilder not equal the original String when checking for a Palindrome?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I am trying to create a function that takes in a String 's' to check if it is a Palindrome :

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
            sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
        }
    }
    
    return sb.toString().equals(sb.reverse().toString());
```

For some reason if I change the return statement to this, it returns true instead of false for certain non palindromes :

```
return sb.reverse().toString().equals(sb.toString());
```

I'm not sure why changing the order of the reverse would cause this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. It's easier for us to help you if you provide a few examples for Strings that show the erroneous behavior you describe

Comment: Because `StringBuilder` is mutable, in the second case you're checking whether the reversed string equals to the same reversed string, which is obviously `true`.

Comment: For example it returns different for this string "race a car". It should ignore any non-alpha numeric characters.

Comment: By the way, `char` is a legacy type, physically incapable of representing most characters. You might want to learn to use code point integer numbers when working with individual characters.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because `reverse()` changes `StringBuilder` and then returns `this`:

```
return sb.toString()                         // "12345", sb -> "12345"
         .equals(
                 sb.reverse().toString()     // "54321", sb -> "54321"
                );                           // false

return sb.reverse().toString()               // "54321", sb -> "54321"
         .equals(
                 sb.toString()               // "54321", sb -> "54321"
                );                           // true
```